# In solr dih import two double in one location

Tags: solr, geolocation, dih, geohashing

What I have now is the two double filds:

```
<field name="x_geo_x_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/> 
<field name="x_geo_y_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>
```

and what I want: the 2 double value in one location field:

```
<field name="x_geo" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0.0,0.0"/>
```

What I tried so far and does't work:

```
<copyField source="*_coordinate" dest="x_geo"/>
<copyField source="x_geo_str" dest="x_geo"/>
```

Any simple solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you where right @nikhil500. ScriptTransformer is one answer, (I'm not sure if this is the simpliest). The dataconfig.xml contains a java function:

```
<script><![CDATA[
            function puttwodouble(row)        {
                var attrVal1 = row.get("GEO_X_WERT");
                var attrVal2 = row.get("GEO_Y_WERT");
                var attrVal = attrVal1 + "," + attrVal2;
                var arr = new java.util.ArrayList()
                arr.add(attrVal1);
                arr.add(attrVal2);
                row.put("store",attrVal);
                row.put("x_geo_str",arr);  
                return row;
            }
]]>
```

whitch will be called:

```
 <entity name="inner_geo_str" transformer="script:puttwodouble"
            query="select GEO_X_WERT, GEO_Y_WERT from FIRMA_GEODATEN where GEO_FIR_NR ='${outer.FIR_NR}' and geo_x_wert != 'NF'">                     
                  <field column="GEO_X_WERT" name="x_geo_x_s"/> 
                  <field column="GEO_Y_WERT" name="x_geo_y_s"/>                     
          </entity>
```

Hope that will help others to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use TemplateTransformer in DIH (data-config.xml):

```
<entity name="p" transformer="TemplateTransformer" ......
<field column="location" template="${p.location_0_coordinate},${p.location_1_coordinate}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to PaulG's answer , you can use [location_rpt](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4) in Solr 4, which supports multi values, but doesn't need to be declared as MultiValue.

```
<field name="region" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) to create `x_geo` field.

Comment: Can you give me a short example, pls?