# How can copy 2 fields data to one field on Solr

Tags: solr

I have a document in solr with `Lat` and `Lng` fields. I need to add a new field called `store` containing data taken from both the `Lat` and `Lng`. I tried to use `copyField` field but I got the error:

> Field store is not multivalued and destination for multiple copyFields (2)

Here is my configuration:

```
<fields>
  <field name="lat" type="sdouble" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="lng" type="sdouble" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
  <field name="store" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields> 

<copyField source="lat" dest="store"/> 
<copyField source="lng" dest="store"/>
```

Is it possible to copy the content of two fields within the same destination field?

Comment: if you see i did not solve this problem.

Comment: I tried this, and the field `store` does not appear on the record

Answer (score 7):

Maybe is it outdated but you can use "updateRequestProcessorChain"

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="composite-position">
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">lat</str>
    <str name="source">lng</str>
    <str name="dest">store</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">store</str>
    <str name="delimiter">;</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Answer (score 6):

Taking your question without context:

> Is it possible to copy the content of two fields within the same
>   destination field?"

The answer is yes, surely.  The example schema does this with  to copy multiple fields to a common "text" field (multiValued) to make searching by one field simpler.

But looking at more context, what you are actually trying to do is determine if Solr's schema.xml with copyField can take an input pair of fields (lat and lon in your case) and concatenate them with an intermediate comma to a particular field.  The answer is no.  You'll have to prepare the data this way when giving it to Solr, or use a DIH transformer if you are using the DIH (the DataImportHandler).  I hesitate to suggest an alternative, but as a hack, you might try putting lat and lon into store_0_coordinate and store_1_coordinate (or maybe it's the other way around).  But really, this isn't a recommended approach even if it might work.

Comment: Can i do this with "UpdateRequestProcessor"?

Comment: You could definitely write an URP to do it.  That's a good use of an URP.

Comment: Thanks you. I'm loading data from *.csv file and there are 3 columns postcode,lat,lng in the *.csv file. Could you please help me with configuration URP?

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at this http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor  and look at an existing one in Solr's code to see how it configures itself from solrconfig.xml.

Comment: Can you give me a short example, pls?

Answer (score 3):

You could try to set `store` as `multivalued`

```
<field name="store" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: if i make `store` field multiValued. i got error on indexing.

Comment: I see, so you actually need is a single valued field populated with the concatenation of the other two fields. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think you can work that out with `copyField` instruction. Maybe this link with help you: http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/116fd7a7yx/copying-few-field-using-copyfield-to-non-multivalued-field

Comment: Thanks for link but i have another situation in my case the `store` field is `solr.LatLonType` type and i need set there `lat,lng` as single value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

[Two double in one location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134958/in-solr-dih-import-two-double-in-one-location/8151210#8151210)

if you can use DIH (Data Importer Handler). Hope thet will help!